# How to get the time the wallet has reached to specific amount?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume the following table:

```
// Wallets
+----+---------+--------+----------------+
| id | user_id | amount |   created_at   |
+----+---------+--------+----------------+
| 1  | 200     | 1000   | 2022-01-01     |
| 2  | 200     | 2000   | 2022-01-01     |
| 3  | 200     | 1500   | 2022-01-02     |
| 4  | 200     | 5000   | 2022-01-03     | -- here
| 5  | 200     | 1000   | 2022-01-03     |   
| 6  | 200     | 3000   | 2022-01-04     |
+----+---------+--------+----------------+
```

Also, the following query calculates the sum of the user's wallet:

```
select sum(amount) from wallets where user_id = 200
```

---

**My question:** I need to select `max(created_at)` when the amount has reached `9000`. So the expected result is `2022-01-03`.

Because `1000` + `2000` + `1500` + `5000` = `9500` and I need to get the time the last transaction happened to reach `9000`, which is `5000` (`#4`) happened at `2022-01-03`.

How can I get it?

---

Here is my query which is wrong:

```
select max(created_at)
from wallets
where user_id = 200
having sum(amount) >= 9000
```

Comment: Please confirm your MySql version

Comment: @Stu it's version 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the cumulative sum line by line then find the lowest date where the amount is 9000 or higher

```
select min(id) id_reached, min(created_at) date_reached from (
  select id, created_at, sum(amount) over(order by id) sum from wallets where user_id = 200
) t1 where sum >= 9000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ee00f1e57077d8fbf889a80fd74aa80)